# React Native - Bottom Sheet Modal: Dynamic height on state change doesn't work every time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

### Situation:

I am using the [Bottom Sheet Modal by Gorham](https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/) to load a modal that shows a stopwatch interface. One element of this interface is a textInput field which is used to label the time that is taken.
I added `onFocus` and `onBlur` to this textInput field to trigger a useState (true/false) to hide/show two elements from the interface, with the goal, to reduce the interface when the user types, and to show more of screen behind the modal.

### Problem:

The `useState` effect works fine. The elements get hidden/shown in perfect speed .
But, the height of the modal doesnt re-render/re-calculate every time. Sometimes the height stays the old height, even though 2/3 of the modal became free thanks to the useState implementation.
With the current code, it works correctly only 60% of the time.

If I click the inputField a bit longer, it works +90% of the time. But my users wont know that this helps, nor should they have to find out.

| Correct | Wrong |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

```js
 const slimModeHandler = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSlimMode((prevState) => {
        return true;
      });
    }, 500);
  };
```

```js
<View style={styles.textInputWrapper}>
        <View style={styles.textInputCol}>
          <BottomSheetTextInput
            style={styles.textInputField}
            placeholder="Name this lap"
            placeholderTextColor={GlobalStyles.colors.font500}
            clearButtonMode="always"
            maxLength={20}
            onChangeText={inputHandlerLapNameState}
            value={modalMemory.modalMemoryLapNameState}
            /* keyboardBehavior="interactive" */
            /* onPressIn={() => {
              setSlimMode((prevState) => {
                return true;
              });
            }} */
            onFocus={slimModeHandler}
            onBlur={() => {
              setSlimMode((prevState) => {
                return false;
              });
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

```js
  const dynamicContainerHeight = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("pre rerendering of dynamicContainerHeight", slimMode);
    //add 500 ms delay to slimMode

    /*  setTimeout(() => { */
    console.log("slimMode during timeOut", slimMode);
    return {
      ...styles.modalContainer,
      paddingBottom: 16,
      /*       height: 120, */
    };
    /*     }, 500); */
  }, [slimMode]);
```

```js
    <BottomSheetView
      style={dynamicContainerHeight}
      onLayout={handleContentLayout}
    >
```

```js
{!slimMode ? (
        <TimerModalCreateStopwatch
          stopwatch={stopwatch}
          handleLeftButtonPress={handleLeftButtonPress}
          handleLeftButtonLongPress={handleLeftButtonLongPress}
          handleLeftButtonLongPressOut={handleLeftButtonLongPressOut}
          handleRightButtonPress={handleRightButtonPress}
          modalMemory={modalMemory}
        />
      ) : null}
```

Unfortunately, everything works 100% of the time on the iOS emulator on my Mac, so I can't learn anything from there. I assume this is because the emulator is less performant than my actual iPhone. (old mac)
Also, when I activate Remote Debugging on my iPhone, it also works 100% of the time on my phone. I assume because everything renders slower on my phone when debugging mode is on?

Ergo, my suspicion is that I have to add some delay somewhere.?

What more have I already tried?

- I tried onPressIn instead of onFocus. This works almost +80% of the time I click on textInput, but (!) now the slimMode (state) changes a tick too *early*, which makes the keyboard *push* the textInput *up* a little too harsh. The animation sequence feels off/wrong.
- I added console.log to check if the "dynamicContainerHeight" gets re-rendered correctly with onFocus and onBlur. Yes, it does.
- I tried putting the dynamicContainerHeight value in state as well.
- I tried useCallback instead of useMemo, and I tried to call it from onFocus.
- I removed "dynamicContainerHeight" as suggested by the package author to "risk" the additional re-render. But this additional re-render did not help.
- I played with "keyboardBehavior" which is one of the custom hooks for textInput by the package author.
- I added delay to dynamicContainerHeight and useState.
- I played with an if (slimMode) statement inside of  "dynamicContainerHeight" to serve a static (instead of dynamics) height when state changes ...
- Added keyboardAvoidingView ...
- Trued collapse method provided by the package author ...

I am not sure what to try next. 3-4 days working on this ...

Comment: You need to define snap points and use the state to control (using the index prop) which snap point the bottom sheet is using.

Comment: I am using this right now for dynamic heights as recommended by the package author. No fixed snap points...
```lang-js
  // variables for all modals
  const initialSnapPoints = useMemo(() => ["CONTENT_HEIGHT"], []);
```